# Java Stream Filter is not letting me use the methods from the class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-stream

Seems I this is an InteliJ issue for me - my comment class has a method called getValue which returns a string. But my below code does not recognize getValue!
Is there something messed up with my InteliJ with Java 8?
The same exact same code works for someone else in my team.

```
 List<Comment> coms = comments.getComment();
    List<Comment> filtered = coms.stream()
                                     .filter(c -> c.getValue().contains("something")) <--- HERE DOES NOT RESOLVE getValue
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is this method visible in class where provided code resides? Maybe `getValue` is package private?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko its visible and its public !  as said this code works on someone else IDE - seems a setting on my IDE is off !

Comment: clear IDE cache, then reindex the application, you will be fine

Comment: @Lunatic tried invalidate Cash and Restart and did not help !

Comment: What happens when you ctrl+click `getValue()`? Is IntelliJ able to find the method? Also, are you able to compile the project without/outside IntelliJ?

Comment: Please share the code full code sample with Comment class. Thanks